# Reapplying for a PhD position at another institute after failing the qualifying exam

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, coursework

It's embarassing, I failed my quals (in PhD ECE). The school is going to give me a terminal masters (w.o. thesis). My gpa is also not that stellar (3.4+), from a mediocre school. But I have a strong will to do a PhD (I enjoy doing research).

My supervisor (along with other co-authors) are supportive in the sense that they are willing to write good letters (i.e. I have a quite decent publication record). So, I am planning to apply this year, my specific queries are --

1. Is it really worth a shot? as I have a "bad record" now (although my transcript will not convey such information, but I am not willing to hide it either)
2. If no.1 is "yes", then how should I justify this to the adcom ? For example, explaining my financial and family problems that I faced during my last years (probably in the SOP)?
3. Is it possible to go to a better school/lab compared to my current one ?

Some particulars:

- I am an international grad student in the US.
- I have a 3.8+ undergrad score from south-east asia (used to be a class topper, if that helps)
- My GRE was also decent.

Comment: I think you can probably break this composite question into smaller questions; i) whether or not to reapply, given the failure of the qualifying exam, ii) whether or not to explain financial and/or familial problems when you reapply, and finally iii) whether or not it's possible to get into a better school (the answer to which is most likely "yes it's possible but..." )

Comment: @posdef: I do not follow, why I should break it into multiple sub-questions.

Comment: because that's how StackExchange sites work, or at least that is the code that is accepted and expected in most SE sites. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: @posdef: Questions 1 and 2 can become one, but I don't think that breaking the questions will help.

Comment: @posdef: It would make __no__ sense to make the first and second questions independent of one another!

Comment: @aeismail whether or not to reapply after having failed the first time round, is one valid, independent question. Whether or not justifying/excusing a prior failure when reapplying is a good idea, is yet another, valid and independent question. And finally whether or not "upgrading" in the situation OP is in, is again a valid question. I am not saying that they are ideal questions, or that they have no overlapping background, but asked separately they _are_ questions that will be relevant to more people than just the OP.

Comment: I think this is fine as one question: "How can I effectively apply to a PhD program in a stronger department?"

Answer (score 5):

You can't let one setback keep you from pursuing your goals or dreams. Yes, it's bad that you failed your quals, but that doesn't mean you should just give up. Having supportive committee members will help a lot when applying to other schools or programs.

Answer (score 4):

Do whatever is up to you to achieve your goals. Don't focus on the previous events but rather try to get some lessons from them not to repeat them in the future. 
Try to focus on your advantages. It seems that you are not in a bad situation. You have a supportive supervisor, not bad scores. Besides, if there is a procedure of reapplying, it means that they also know that someone may need a second chance. 
So, answering your questions.

1. Certainly. At the end you may say, at least I tried everything. Just keep moving and you will see the directions. If you are staying in the same place, you will never know whether your path is right or not. Give it a try.
2. You don't have to justify anything. If they ask, then slightly explain the situation. They are not monsters.
3. You can apply to a few places simultaneously. Of course it is worth trying. If you have time to manage that.

As it was mentioned, you can also try to apply to another programs in your or other universities (if you want)/
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Consider applying to a different school or switching majors in the same university. Yes it is certainly worth a short. And no do not mention financial or family problems in the SOP.

Also consider joining the workforce. It is good to have options in hand. A PhD is not very useful unless you want to stick in academia which means low pay, being stuck in small city in the middle of nowhere, dealing with procrastinating students, begging NSF for funding etc.

ECE Masters are paid well in the industry and most PhDs I know work on "stuff" that a Masters can easily do. There are always exceptions to everything.

Comment: Why is a PhD only useful in academia? Many industry jobs hire PhDs. And why would you be stuck in a small town in the middle of nowhere? Most universities I'm familiar with are in cities.

Comment: If you want a research career (as opposed to a development career), a PhD is essentially a prerequisite today.

Comment: _Most universities I'm familiar with are in cities_ — This is not the same as "most universities".  Ahem.